# Как узнать из программы имя пользователя?

Tags: c++, linux

Написал игру, которая сохраняет результат в файл. При этом хочу, чтобы файл сохранялся в `/home/user/` где `user` - имя пользователя. Как узнать имя пользователя из программы?

Comment: переменная окружения HOME содержит домашний каталог пользователя. И это не обязательно /home/username

Comment: Сохранять надо согласно стандартам fdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Linux переменная окружения `USER` дает имя пользователя, но лучше брать сразу  `HOME` - она содержит путь к домашнему каталогу текущего пользователя.

Comment: подскажите, а как ее "взять"? Всмысле записать в `string` или `char *`.

Comment: Так вроде как для этого есть функция `getenv`. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html

Answer (score 2):

Переменные `$HOME` и `$USER` можно легко подменить, поэтому их хорошо использовать в большинстве приложений, когда пользователю желательно предоставить такую возможность.

Если этого необходимо избежать, например в suid-приложении, то лучше использовать напрямую Сишные системные/библиотечные вызовы: [`getuid ()`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getuid&category=2&russian=0) и [`getpwuid ()`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getpwuid&category=3&russian=0):

```
struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid (getuid ());
char *name = pwd->pw_name;
char *dir = pwd->pw_dir;
```

Также существует *MT-Safe* версия `getpwuid ()` — [`getpwuid_r()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid_r).

Comment: Существует также *getent()*.

Comment: getent(3) нет... а (1) в сишном вопросе — не интересно...

Comment: Кто-то запрещает посмотреть в исходники?